# Change jupyter notebook style in VS Code (css file)

Tags: jupyter-notebook, visual-studio-code

I encountered some problems when trying to change the layout of the markdown cells of my jupyter notebook.

I do not like the default display of tables and I want to change it. I am trying to use the default css from github.

I do not have lines that separates the rows and columns:

[image: I do not have lines that separates the rows and columns]

I tried to set this in my settings.json but it did not work

```
    "markdown.styles": [
        "./.vscode/github-markdown.css"
    ]
```

I have also tried to add something find here (https://www.kaggle.com/learn-forum/129348)

```
from IPython.display import HTML
HTML(''.format(open('.vscode/github-markdown.css').read()))
```

Can you help me ?